# How to make routes transition animation in Angular RC.5?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-animation

So `routeOnDeactivate` has been removed. How to animation routes in transit? The official document is not stating it clear

Comment: You could use a CanDeactivate Guard for this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42948545/5155810

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet supported
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9845#issuecomment-232476173

You might be able to create a custom `<router-outlet>` derived from the existing one to support animations.
It needs to keep the old component until the animation is completed to be able to do a transition animation. There was an `onDone` callback added to animations to make this easier.

Comment: So in order to delay route deactivation by 400 ms, all I can do is to return a `Promise` resolve after 400 ms?

Comment: I didn't dive deeper into this topic yet myself. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9845#issuecomment-235799008 Do you think it is possible to animate other component or HTML element with a state transition triggered?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Did you see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html

Comment: Yes, I have. I have a loading screen cover in my app. When page transit, it fade in and out accordingly, it works properly in NG2 beta but not in RC as `routeOnDeactivate` removed.

Comment: What about https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-deactivate-guard

Comment: Just stumbled upon https://github.com/angular/angular.io/pull/2138/files which might help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122364/discussion-between-aokaddaoc-and-gunter-zochbauer).